# Download videos from vimeo

Tags: c#, video, vimeo

I'm trying to download videos from vimeo) with c#.
The problem is that I receive the code 200 (with a page that says "Permision denied") when I have to receive de code 302 to do a redirection.
This is the code:

```
string url = "http://player.vimeo.com/play_redirect?clip_id=" + clip_id + "&sig=" + request_signature + "&time=" + request_signature_expires + "&quality=" + hd + "&codecs=H264,VP8,VP6&type=moogaloop_local&embed_location=";

_VideoURL = GetHttpSpecial(url, cookies);

public string GetHttpSpecial(string url, CookieContainer cookies)
        {
            string html = "";
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
            request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language: nl,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3");
            request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate");
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0";
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            request.Timeout = 20000;
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            foreach (Cookie cookie in response.Cookies)
            {
                cookies.Add(cookie);
            }
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                try
                {
                    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                    try
                    {
                        html = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        reader.Close();
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    response.Close();
                }
                return html;
            }
            else
            {
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Found)
                {
                    return response.Headers["Location"].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    return "error: server returned status description:" + response.StatusDescription;
                }
            }
        }
```

Could you help me, please?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Sara, welcome to the site. Are you seeing this when you are programmatically trying to download videos or just using vimeo via a site?

Comment: I'm trying to download a video from vimeo using an application programming by me

Answer (score 1):

This code is works for me.
I created new WPF project with simple button. Here is code-behind:

```
private Dictionary<int, CookieContainer> m_cookieContainer = new Dictionary<int, CookieContainer>();

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            HttpWebRequest req = CreateRequest("http://vimeo.com/42082443");
            req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0";
            req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
            req.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage] = "ru,en;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,uk;q=0.3";
            req.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding] = "gzip, deflate";
            req.KeepAlive = true;
            req.Timeout = 20000;
            req.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
            using (HttpWebResponse response = GetResponse(req))
            {
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    string pageData = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

                    string clipId = null;
                    if (Regex.Match(pageData, @"clip_id=(\d+)", RegexOptions.Singleline).Success)
                    {
                        clipId = Regex.Match(pageData, @"clip_id=(\d+)", RegexOptions.Singleline).Groups[1].ToString();
                    }
                    else if (Regex.Match(pageData, @"(\d+)", RegexOptions.Singleline).Success)
                    {
                        clipId = Regex.Match(pageData, @"(\d+)", RegexOptions.Singleline).Groups[1].ToString();
                    }

                    string sig = Regex.Match(pageData, "\"signature\":\"(.+?)\"", RegexOptions.Singleline).Groups[1].ToString();
                    string timestamp = Regex.Match(pageData, "\"timestamp\":(\\d+)", RegexOptions.Singleline).Groups[1].ToString();

                    string videoUrl = string.Format("http://player.vimeo.com/play_redirect?clip_id={0}&sig={1}&time={2}&quality=hd&codecs=H264,VP8,VP6&type=moogaloop_local&embed_location=", clipId, sig, timestamp);

                    req = CreateRequest(videoUrl);
                    req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
                    req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0";
                    req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
                    req.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage] = "ru,en;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,uk;q=0.3";
                    req.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding] = "gzip, deflate";
                    req.KeepAlive = true;
                    req.Referer = "http://a.vimeocdn.com/p/flash/moogaloop/5.2.25/moogaloop.swf?v=1.0.0";
                    req.Timeout = 20000;
                    req.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
                    using (HttpWebResponse response2 = GetResponse(req))
                    {
                        if (response2.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Found)
                        {
                            string location = response2.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.Location];
                            MessageBox.Show(location);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private CookieContainer GetCookieContainerPerThread()
        {
            int managedThreadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
            lock (typeof(MainWindow))
            {
                if (!this.m_cookieContainer.ContainsKey(managedThreadId))
                {
                    CookieContainer container = new CookieContainer();
                    this.m_cookieContainer.Add(managedThreadId, container);
                }
            }
            return this.m_cookieContainer[managedThreadId];
        }

        public HttpWebRequest CreateRequest(string url)
        {
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            req.CookieContainer = this.GetCookieContainerPerThread();
            //this.InitProxy(req);
            return req;
        }

        public HttpWebResponse GetResponse(HttpWebRequest req)
        {
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            this.GetCookieContainerPerThread().Add(response.Cookies);
            return response;
        }
```

Comment: I tried your answer, but I can only see "location": how can I download video using that location? Thanks

Comment: @Marco Location should be a direct link to physical video file on remote server. Pass it to WebClient.DownloadFile

Comment: Well, it worked for the video link you used. But if I try with [this](http://vimeo.com/30881879) or [this other](http://vimeo.com/17913746) location is null. Do you have any idea? Thank you so much

Comment: Ok, problem solved. If you want you could add this info to your post: you're setting `quality=hd` while composing `string videoUrl = ...`; if video is not HD, returned location will be null. Simply remove that part `&quality=hd` and location will be returned ok. So, maybe you can first try to check for an HD video; then, if it's not found, switch to the normal one...

Comment: @Marco yes indeed, I used it long time ago and forgot about that, you can make check for response status code and null, and if failed, repeat same operation but without quality param

Comment: Is it possible to download vimeo videos without providing credentials?

Comment: is there a newer version of this code? When I run it, both signature and timestamp can't be parsed, and the status after the last request is never "Found", but "Moved Permanently".

There are several dates in the HTML file, but I am not sure which one to parse: is it the date in which the video was uploaded?

Answer (score 0):

Sara, use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to examine the request/responses to ensure you are sending the same. When I watch my playing a video normally using the website, there is a `vimeo` cookie that is passed backwards and forwards that isn't when you call the play link directly.

Perhaps try making a request against the home page first to get the vimeo cookie (from `Repsonse.GetResponseHeader("Set-Cookie")` and use that in your further calls.

It could be that Vimeo don't allow requests that haven't been referred from their website so you might also have to do a

```
request.Referer =
            "http://a.vimeocdn.com/[[IMPORT]]/player.vimeo.com/assets/flash/moogaloop/5.2.8/controllers/videoController.swf";
```

Comment: I've checked it with Fiddle and the request/responses are:
<pre><code>

# Result Protocol Host URL Body Caching Content-Type Process Comments Custom 
118 302 HTTP player.vimeo.com /play_redirect?clip_id=33735037&sig=85b60dd8d19ec06b9307fbc1e733048d&time=1324303943&quality=hd&codecs=H264,VP8,VP6&type=moogaloop_local&embed_location= 20 no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate  Expires: Fri, 25 Feb 1983 09:30:00 GMT text/html; charset=UTF-8 avp:3544   
119 200 HTTP av.vimeo.com /38970/772/76932486.mp4?token=1324304859_f553bbbfb98f07551487cefe95ec3135 55.608.510  video/mp4 avp:3544   
</code></pre>

Comment: With my code in c# I never receive the 302 response. I receive a 200 code with Permision denied.
I've try with a referer, but I'm not able to redirect.

Thanks